# How does a pointer event passed as an argument in debounce?

Tags: javascript

I am confused about how the pointer event is passed to the debounce() in addEventListener(). For the constant variable `multiply` it takes the two arguments which are passed as `args` in `debounce()`. However, when it is used in `.addEventListener()` I only see the syntax that defines the function. So how does the pointer event is passed as an argument like the first example?

```js
function debounce(func, timeout = 1000) {
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      func(...args);
    }, timeout);
  };
}

const multiply = debounce((x, y) => console.log(x * y));
multiply(10, 10); //I see that this takes the arguments that assign to x and y 
 
button.addEventListener(
  "click",
  debounce((e) => console.log("clicked")));
//but here I am confused how the pointer event is being passed as an argument
```

Comment: It's received a callback as first parameter `e` is the event object of button element that includes the info of current element has attached event

Comment: _“I only see the syntax that defines the function”_ — You mean `debounce((e) => console.log("clicked"))`, right? Yes, this results in a function, as is expected for the second argument of `addEventListener`. `addEventListener` calls the function with the argument. See [Where do the parameters in a javascript callback function come from?](/q/34624634/4642212) and look up how higher-order functions work in JS.